# Rails: How to display "alternate" link tag for every language

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, localization, internationalization

I can't find out how to display a link tag in the head of my html pages containing the URLs the same page in every other avbailable language.

Here is my wrong current solution:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="/es" hreflang="es-es" />
<link rel="alternate" href="/ru" hreflang="ru-ru" />
```

And here is my desired outcome that I can't figure how to make:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="/es/blog/i_like_coding" hreflang="es-es" />
<link rel="alternate" href="/ru/blog/i_like_coding" hreflang="ru-ru" />
```

I tried to use this code, but can't strip away `<a>` tag from `href` itself:

```
<%= link_to "hi", :locale => 'ru' %>
```

Result for my unsuccessful try:

```
<a href="/ru/blog/i_like_coding">hi</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The link_to helper creates an a tag so you don't want to use that helper method. You simply use html.

```
 <link rel="alternate" href="/es/blog/i_like_coding" hreflang="es-es" />
```

Comment: This doesn't solve problem because its wrapped in `<a>` tag and not `<link>` tag as it should be. @margo

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your intentions, I've updated my answer.

Comment: ok, but how can I request path with different locales for each language? similar as this can do it `<%= link_to "hi", :locale => 'ru' %>` @margo

Comment: You haven't given enough info about how your application knows which languages to provide an alternate link to. If they're stored in a d/b table, you could get all the languages in the controller and use them in the view,  <% @languages.each do |language| %> <link rel="alternate" href="/#{language}/blog/i_like_coding" hreflang="#{language}-#{language}" /><% end %>